# Why i get "Error 1181" when compile makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, cl

makefile

```
main: main.cpp detours/detours.lib
CL /std:c++17 /EHsc /Fe:bin\test /I . /I detours/ /W2 /O2 /LD $** user32.lib
```

And after i get error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "bin.obj"
make: *** [Makefile:2: main] Error 2
```

Why he want open bin.obj ? Bin is folder and CL don't create obj from bin.
How to fix this problem ?

Upd, this is full code from makefile. Second line have tabulation. Here i removed bin folder from output.

```
main: main.cpp detours/detours.lib
    CL /std:c++17 /EHsc /Fe:test /I . /I detours/ /W2 /O2 /LD $** user32.lib
```

If i remove bin folder from output in makefile and same from directory, i get error `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "detours.obj"`

Output

```
make -f Makefile
CL /std:c++17 /EHsc /Fe:test /I . /I detours/ /W2 /O2 /LD * user32.lib
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.23.28107 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.23.28107.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.dll
/dll
/implib:test.lib
detours
helper.h
main.obj
main.obj
Makefile
packets.h
functions.h
user32.lib
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'detours.obj'
make: *** [Makefile:2: main] Error 2
```

Comment: My crystal ball says you do not have a `bin` directory. Also, the `/Fe` option does not take a `:` as argument.

Comment: @Botje You can see image. I have bin folder... [link](https://i.imgur.com/maA2btg.png)

Comment: @drescherjm , i remove `:` , and get next error `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "bin\test.obj"`
I added space between `:` and `bin` , i get the first error.

Comment: @Botje [Yes it does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fe-name-exe-file?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Please post your makefile _verbatim_ (it cannot be as shown as you are missing indentation that would prevent its execution). I suspect there is something going on we cannot see, perhaps a hidden character or additional space. cl seems to think `bin\test` is an input.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I updated my message in header. In second line not having hidden character or additional space. You can see my screenshot from notepad++ with enabled 'see all characters' [screen](https://i.imgur.com/FM661Rr.png)